# Change php args array depending on the window width

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml, args

I'm using javascript to detect window width:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
        if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML="1140";}
        else if ($(window).width() > 1050 && $(window).width() < 1199) {
            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML="970";}
        else if ($(window).width() > 820 && $(window).width() < 1049) {
            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML="760";}
    </script>
```

It's work, but i need to change php array depending on monitor width.

```
    <?php $args = array(
         'post_type'      => 'post',
         'posts_per_page' => 6,
    ); ?>
```

So "Post per page" should change depending on monitor width

How to put Post per page argument in innerHTML or how to make it in another similar way

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `ajax`. Here's an example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function sendParams(arg) {
                $.post('test.php', {params: arg}, function(data) { 
                    console.log(data);
                });
            } 
            if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
                sendParams("1140");
            }
            else if ($(window).width() > 1050 && $(window).width() < 1199) {
                sendParams("970");
            }
            else if ($(window).width() > 820 && $(window).width() < 1049) {
                sendParams("760");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['params'])) {
        $args = array(
         'post_type'      => 'post',
         'posts_per_page' => $_POST['params']
        );
    }
?>
```